# Spring Integration application with external Web Services monitoring

Tags: java, spring, cxf, spring-integration, spring-ws

Currently I have an application with Spring Integration DSL that has AMQP inbound gateway with different service activators, each service activator has kind of logic to decide, transform and call external web services (currently with CXF), but all this logic is in code without Spring Integration components.

These service activators are monitored, in the output channel that returns data from this application is an AMQP adapter that sends headers to a queue (after that, all headers are processed and saved in a database for future analysis). This works well, these service activators even have elapsed time in headers.

Now, the problem is, that I need to monitor external web service calls, like elapsed time in each operation, which service endpoint and operation was called, if an error occurred.

I've been thinking that logic code in each service activator should be converted into a Spring Integration flow, in each service activator, would call a new gateway with the name of the operation of the web service in a header, and monitoring every flow as currently I had been doing.

So, I'm not sure if this manual approach is the better approach, so I wonder if there is a way to get the name of the service operation with some kind of interceptor or something similar with CXF or Spring WS to avoid setting the name of the operation in headers in a manual way? What would be your recommendation?

To have more context here is the Spring Integration configuration:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(simpleMessageListenerContainer())
            .mappedReplyHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
            .mappedRequestHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
            .errorChannel(gatewayErrorChannel())
            .requestChannel(gatewayRequestChannel())
            .replyChannel(gatewayResponseChannel())
        )
        .enrichHeaders(new Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(HeaderEnricherSpec t) {
                    t.headerExpression(AMQPConstants.START_TIMESTAMP, "T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()");
                }

         })
        .transform(getCustomFromJsonTransformer())
        .route(new HeaderValueRouter(AMQPConstants.OPERATION_ROUTING_KEY))
        .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayRequestChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayResponseChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

private IntegrationFlow loggerOutboundFlowTemplate(MessageChannel fromMessageChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fromMessageChannel)
        .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(new RabbitTemplate(getConnectionFactory()))
            .exchangeName(LOGGER_EXCHANGE_NAME)
            .routingKey(LOGGER_EXCHANGE_ROUTING_KEY)
            .mappedRequestHeaders("*"))
        .get();
}
```

And here is a typical service activator, as you can see, all this logic could be an integration flow:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="myServiceActivator", outputChannel = ConfigurationBase.MAP_RESPONSE_CHANNEL_NAME)
public Message<Map<String, Object>> myServiceActivator(Map<String, Object> input, @Header(AMQPConstants.SESSION) UserSession session) throws MyException {
    Message<Map<String, Object>> result = null;
    Map<String, Object> mapReturn = null;

    ExternalService port = serviceConnection.getExternalService();
    try {
        if (input.containsKey(MappingConstants.TYPE)) {
            Request request = transformer
                    .transformRequest(input, session);

            Response response = port
                    .getSomething(request);

            utils.processBackendCommonErrors(response.getCode(), response.getResponse());
            mapReturn = transformer.convertToMap(response);
        } else {
            Request request = transformer
                    .transformRequest(input, session);

            Response response = port
                    .getSomethingElse(request);

            utils.processBackendCommonErrors(response.getCode(),
                    response.getResponse());
            mapReturn = transformer.convertToMap(response);
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        String message = "unexcepted exception from the back-end";
        logger.warn(message, e);
        throw MyException.generateTechnicalException(message, null, e);
    }

    result = MessageBuilder.withPayload(mapReturn)
            .build();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far so good. Or I don't understand the problem, or you are not clear where it is.

Anyway you always can proxy any Spring Service with the [AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), since it looks like you are pointing to the code:

```
Response response = port
                .getSomething(request);
```

When this (or similar) method is called, some `MethodInterceptor` can perform desired tracing logic and send result to some `MessageChannel` for further analysis or anything else to do:

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    // Extract required operation name and start_date from the MethodInvocation
    Object result = invocation.proceed();
    // Extract required data from the response
    // Build message and send to the channel
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am logging all that is contained in my headers, with the current service activators (SA), the SA name is in the header so the log contains which SA is executed, and in the same way I would like to have in headers the name of external service and operation that is called. I think a new integration flow could be used, but new gateway with the name of operation should be inserted as header from the first invocation, so I wonder if there is an automatic way to get the name of the WS operation, something to get this without setting the name operation manually.

Comment: What you mean with "operation"? Where is it? Who controls that? So, just use that stuff and provide it as headers into the message for logs.

Comment: I mean, the third party web service method or operation, if using AOP, web service interceptor or header enricher could I get the name of the web service method and put in some way this method name in headers without setting the name manually as header when calling the gateway

Comment: Paying attention again to your first response, with AOP, and the methodInterceptor how could return to a MessageChannel the info that I want? How could I involve that mehotdInterceptor in a Spring Integration Flow?

Comment: I pointed you to the documentation about AOP. This doesn't relate to Spring Integration. You show me code where you call external service, I show you the way how to reach a flexible solution without changing your logic. You still don't show me where is your operation name, but I believe that you will be able to extract it from that MethodInterceptor. If you want to change it to IntegrationFlow, that would be a fully different question

Comment: Thanks Artem for your responses, let me keep trying to understand the problem, and your proposed solution, and maybe later will try to update my question